# Airplane Mode in Network Settings

Tags: wireless, network-manager

The [Gnome documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.3/net-wireless-airplane.html.en) states:

> Switch Airplane Mode on. This will turn off your wireless connection
>   until you switch off airplane mode again.
>
> Using Airplane Mode will completely turn off both wireless and
>   Bluetooth connections.

I have **Airplane Mode** turned on in my Network Settings, but still am able to access both Wireless and Bluetooth.

So, what is the real purpose of having Airplane Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug.  If it doesn't do what it says on the tin, then by definition it's unwanted behavior.  Consider helping the GNOME team by [filing a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/).

Comment: If you are getting "fail to flush all tx fifo queues" from your iwlwifi wireless kernel module (pertaining to Intel Centrino N cards) this is probably why.